# Tricks to make the map feel bigger than it actually is

Tags: maps, rpg, level-design, open-world, top-down

I am planning out a fantasy rpg. Based on its story and mechanics, it will span over multiple countries and continents. However, even at the highest possible funding and management, I may not be able to create a big enough map. My solution: Scale it way down.

Of course, this is not an original idea, dozens of games have done this. However, I am not really show how to without the players seeing that it's small.

What are ways that I could make the map be really small, but appear to be really huge?

For some details:

- The game is top-down, and in a style such as Stardew Valley or Chrono Trigger
- The design is a mix of Dark Souls and Skyrim, with a little GTA influence
- While there is of course a lot of walking, there is transportation, including dragon-riding, drivable wagons, and horses. Might include teleportation, but it will cost extra.

Comment: These types of games will often have two kinds of maps/areas - detailed destinations like towns/temples/dungeons, as well as the "connective tissue" you move through to get from one destination to another (sometimes a separate overworld map, or sometimes a path navigated the same way as the destination zones). Is your worry more about one of these types of areas vs the other?

Answer (score 1):

### Cutscenes and travel minigames

You mention Chrono Trigger: do you recall the racing minigame in 2300 AD? That made the location feel much bigger.

Instead of covering distance on screen, take up the player's time: during wagon riding (I imagine a caravan), make random events play out. Give the player something to do. Add night maps around the campfire. Then you don't need to show that 100km have been traversed; it suffices to have a couple of day and night events in succession.

### World map

World maps help to convey size without requiring to model each square kilometer in detail:

Secret of Mana, for example, had these fast travel trampoline thingies that would show you launch and landing, which helped to show distances and the layout of the land. This series employs travel by sea and air eventually so you'd traverse the world map, but it's mostly set dressing as you go from landing spot to landing spot.

That's different from the Final Fantasy games for SNES which allow to move on the world map iself, including random battles.

The idea is to provide detail maps + a zoomed out world map that's interactible, i.e. goes beyond a mere map screen showing one's location.

### Many detail maps

Chained Echoes instead uses tons of large detail maps to convey distances. That's similar to esp. ""Secret of Mana 2"" (Seiken Densetsu 3) where you'd have all these beautiful locations when you travel on foot prior to unlocking air travel.

String together smaller detail maps, vary the tileset, and fade through black during transitions to convey "time has passed" and players might be able to imagine something happened during map transitions whenever the map-stitching is imperfect.

That takes the most map-making time, but I'm personally not convinced this actually improves the game. I'd favor caravan rides any day of the week :)

Answer (score 1):

- Don't let the player see too much of the world at once. In top-down, this can be accomplished by having the camera closer to the player-character. In 1st or 3rd person, it can be accomplished by having a lot of buildings, walls, mountains and other objects that break lines of sight in the world. The result is that the player needs more time to fully explore the world, which makes it seem a lot larger.
- Don't let the player traverse too quickly. The faster the player can move through the game world, the smaller it seems.
- Don't let the player go everywhere too early. You can prevent that via gating. Gating means that you place a lot of obstacles that prevent the player from entering certain areas which then get subsequently unlocked as the story and/or the players ability progress. This prevents the player from exploring the game world too quickly, while still letting the player know that there is lots of content they haven't seen yet.
- Make good use of the locations you have by making sure the player wants to spend as much time in them as possible. You can do that by encouraging the player to explore each location very thoroughly by placing a lot of hidden collectibles and resources for the player to find. Or encourage the player to fight through the same dungeon multiple times. This can be done by optional sidequests which prompt the player to revisit a location they already cleared. Or you can give the player an intrinsic motivation to revisit locations by changing them slightly as the game progresses and thus promising a new experience. For example by adding stronger enemies, but also better rewards to old areas. Or by giving the player new abilities that allow them to interact with old areas in new ways.

Comment: Re: "Make good use of locations," one of my favourite things is when I'm able to return to an old area with new context. Maybe I have a new quest or new purpose (like a crafting material available here now that I couldn't get before). Maybe I have a macguffin that will let me access part of the area I couldn't ealier. Maybe previously it was hostile but now it's friendly (or vice versa). Maybe something has changed in the world and all the NPCs have new stuff I can talk to them about. All this makes an old place feel novel, and gives a sense of mastery in applying memory from the last visit.